# How to break long autowire exclude glob

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection, bundle

I have next lines in `services.yml`:

```
services:
    _defaults:
         autowire: true
         autoconfigure: false

    AppBundle\CompanyInfo\:
        resource: '../../../src/AppBundle/CompanyInfo/*'
        # TODO: Find how to break this line.
        exclude: '../../../src/AppBundle/CompanyInfo/**/{Company.php,CompanyAddress.php,MultipleCompanyAttributesParserDecorator.php,Executive.php,Person.php,ForeignCompanyFounder.php,PersonFounder.php,RussianCompanyFounder.php,EconomicActivity.php,EconomicActivityInfo.php}'
```

How can I break exclude glob to multiple lines?

I need something like this (doesn't work):

```
exclude: >
    ../../../src/AppBundle/CompanyInfo/**/{Company.php,
    CompanyAddress.php,
    MultipleCompanyAttributesParserDecorator.php,
    Executive.php,
    Person.php,
    ForeignCompanyFounder.php,
    PersonFounder.php,
    RussianCompanyFounder.php,
    EconomicActivity.php,
    EconomicActivityInfo.php}
```

Comment: Can you try to set only two spaces before each line of your string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: You say that the `>` operator doesn’t work for you, can you give us an error message?